# MySQL: How to determine when a row was last accessed in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am inserting rows in a huge database (millions of records) using the INSERT IGNORE INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column IF(statement) technique. I am also recording the number of new rows, updated rows and unchanged rows on every run.

I have a column 'last_accessed' which is of type 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. However, obviously this column is not updated when mysql_affected_rows is zero, but only when it is 1 (insert) or 2 (duplicate key update).

If I update it within ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE I will not be able to distinguish between updated and unchanged rows.

Manually updating the last_accessed row is very intensive operation and I want to avoid it.

What technique can I use to solve my problem? Also, is there a mysql query (similar to mysql_insert_id()) that will return the last accessed row id (regardless of operation)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a store_procedured to return the dataset and update that field when calling it. It's best I can think of for you to do so.